# Consulta con SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo una BD en SQLServer en la cual hay una columna llamada "Celulares", el problema de eso fue que los usuarios ingresaron su teléfono de dos formas:

Forma A: **0351-153111222**. En este caso necesito quitar el **0**, quitar el **-** y quitar el **15**, quedando como forma final **3513111222**

Forma B: **153111222**. En este caso necesito quitar el **15** y añadir al principio el **351** quedando como forma final **3513111222**

Como no quiero hacerle un Update a toda la tabla, quería saber si hay alguna consulta o función que me permita "acomodar" o "arreglar" esas formas para que se vean de la siguiente manera:

Forma que quiero que se vea: **3513111222**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que si la entrada es un texto libre puedes encontrarte muchas incidencias. Resolver el caso que cuentas es sencillo, simplemente con un `RIGHT` lo solucionas.
Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT Nombre, RIGHT(Telefono, 10) as Telefono from Celulares
```

Aunque puede que se me escape algo pues en tu pregunta no me cuadran los números:
Convertir Forma B: 153111222 en 3513111222 no se parecen al inicio me despista. De todas formas, jugando con `LEFT`, `RIGHT` y `SUBSTRING` en la consulta lo deberías poder solucionar.

**EDITO la respuesta**:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Telefono, 2, 3) + SUBSTRING(Telefono, 8, 10) as Telefono 
from Celulares
WHERE CHARINDEX ('-', Telefono) > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '351' + SUBSTRING(Telefono, 3, 10) as Telefono from Celulares
WHERE CHARINDEX ('-', Telefono) = 0
```

La consulta hace un `UNION` entre dos consultas, la primera construye el teléfono con dos 'SUBSTRING' cuando detecta que hay un guión `-`. La segunda lo hace cuando no lo hay.

Comment: No, eso no responde mi pregunta. Porque lo que yo necesito es una consulta/función que añada o quite números conforme a como está cargado el número: Por Ejemplo, caso A: `0351-153111222` necesito quitar ese "0", quitar el guíon y quitar ese "15", quedando como forma final `3513111222`.

Comment: Modificaré la pregunta

Comment: @Franqo Balsamo He editado la respuesta, espero que se ajuste a lo que pedías.

Comment: Vale, me ha servido :)